# Datetime formats and JSON data in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I'm having an issue with date/time formats in ASP.NET/C#.  I have my SQL Server database set up with a PostDate field set to a type of "datetime".  But it's saving the date in a strange format. I added a new row through a form and I got this as the date/time string:

`2012-09-28 14:56:48.910`

When it gets parsed by JSON.NET it gets even stranger.  I get:

```
2012-09-28T14:56:48.91
```

The date and time are obviously correct, but how do I set things so that I can parse the date into a human-friendly way?  There isn't really any code to post because the date is being added when the row is inserted. I'd like to format this as "Sept. 28, 2012 2:56 pm". How do I do that?  Do I need to format the string before or after it's parsed as JSON?

Comment: It's even more strange if you don't use JSON.NET :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not a "strange" format at all. The second form is ISO-8601; the first is ISO-8601 without the `T`. Considering [the strange formats you *can* get in JSON](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx), it looks like you've been let off pretty lightly!

Serialization formats aren't *meant* to be user-friendly, particularly - they're meant to be machine-to-machine formats.

I would *hope* that JSON.NET would give you a `DateTime` after parsing; it should only be giving you the ISO-8601 format after you've converted back to JSON.

If you've got a `DateTime` that you want to format for user consumption, there are all kinds of options with [standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) and [custom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) format strings. Don't forget that you should respect the culture of the user, as far as possible - so make sure you're taking appropriate steps to either set the thread's current culture to be the user's one, or that you're passing the culture explicitly to `DateTime.ToString` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it in C#:

```
.ToString("MMM d yyyy, h:mm tt")
```